# ¿Como usar la opcion i18n en un datepicker de Uikit Framework?

Tags: javascript, i18n, datepicker

Buenas, quisiera saber como usar la opcion de i18n de un Datepicker de uikit.

en su sitio oficial explican que usa un objeto Json. http://getuikit.com/docs/datepicker.html

pero no logro hacer que funcione.

mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<form class="uk-form">
<input type="text" data-uk-datepicker="{weekstart:0, format:'DD.MM.YYYY', i18n: { months:['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre']}}">
</form>
```

¿Podria alguien decirme como se debe usar correctamente?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código funciona bien si añado las bibliotecas online:

```html
<link href="http://getuikit.com/docs/css/uikit.docs.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getuikit.com/docs/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getuikit.com/src/js/components/datepicker.js"></script>

<form class="uk-form">
  <input type="text" data-uk-datepicker="{weekstart:0, format:'DD.MM.YYYY', i18n: { months:['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre']}}">
</form>
```

Probablemente el fallo es que alguno de los ficheros no se está incluyendo correctamente. Para solucionarlo, asegúrate de que estás incluyendo todo lo que necesitas:

- jQuery
- UIkit
- UIkit Datepicker

Si los estás incluyendo todos, comprueba la consola de errores para ver si hay algún error 404 (puede que la ruta no sea válida).

Comment: Las librerias estaban añadidas correctamente y el datepicker funcionaba, lo que no funcionaba era la traduccion de los meses, de manera local sigue sin funcionar pero al colocarlo en un servidor a comenzado a funcionar.

Comment: ¿habías añadido las librerías como `//url.a.libreria.js`?

Comment: Las añadi igual a como lo hiciste en la respuesta, y funciona en el hosting, pero no en mi servidor local. Debo suponer que tendra mal las rutas o algo no funciona bien.